# Android version react-native app only connects the Bluetooth to the app after restarting the app

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth, react-native

The android version of the app I'm working on needs to connect to a bluetooth device to the app(NOT THE DEVICE).  First, we scan for a device:

```
    setupScanCompleteListener() {
        this.scanCompleteListener = someBluetoothEventEmitter.addListener('someDeviceScanComplete', foundDevice => {
        console.log('AddDevicePage: setupScanCompleteListener: foundDevice: ', foundDevice);
        // console.log('AddDevicePage: setupScanCompleteListener: devices: ' + foundDevice.deviceAddresses);
        let newDeviceAddress = this.findNewDeviceAddress(foundDevice.deviceAddresses);
        this.newDeviceAddress = newDeviceAddress;
        if (newDeviceAddress) {
            console.log('inside newDeviceAddress: ', newDeviceAddress);
            this.setConnectTimeout();
            someBluetoothManager.connectDeviceWithMacAddress(newDeviceAddress, error => {
                console.log('Could not connectDeviceWithMacAddress: ', error)
            });
            this.props.addToTotalNumberofInitialDevices();
            console.log('this is after someBluetoothManager.connectDeviceWithMacAddress gets fired: ', this.props);
        }
        else {
            this.props.endSearchingForDeviceFunc();
            console.log('No new devices found', this.props);
            this.handleNoNewDevicesFound();
        }
    });
}
```

A newDeviceAddress is always found, which means that `someBluetoothManager.connectDeviceWithMacAddress` always gets fired.

In the million times that I've fired this off, I've never seen an error message.  However the listener that is set up to detect when the device is connected only works consistently after I've restarted the app.  Also, I never see an ERROR_ON_CONNECTING message in the console.logs.  I

```
setupDeviceStatusChangedListener() {
        this.someDeviceStatusChanged = someBluetoothEventEmitter.addListener('someDeviceStatusChanged', event => {
            console.log('someDeviceStatusChanged: event: ', event)
            if (EventUtils.eventCodeEquals(event, 'CONNECTED')) {
                console.log('right after device gets connected ', event)
                this.handleDeviceConnected();
            }
            else if (EventUtils.eventCodeEquals(event, 'ERROR_ON_CONNECTING')) {
                console.log('inside the else if block: ', event);
                this.handleNoNewDevicesFound();
            }
        });
    }
```

I've compared logs in Android Studio to see what the difference between the first time I try to connect and the second time.

The first time I try to connect I see this in the logs:

```
2019-02-25 15:39:54.257 23934-24032/com.someapp D/com.facebook.FacebookSdk: getGraphApiVersion: v3.0


2019-02-25 15:39:54.296 23934-24032/com.someapp D/TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON
2019-02-25 15:39:54.327 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libfb.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.328 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libfolly_json.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.328 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libgifimage.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.328 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.328 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog_init.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.328 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.328 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libicu_common.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.328 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libimagepipeline.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.329 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.329 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libsomefittingjni.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.329 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libprivatedata.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.329 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libreactnativejni.so: deferring to libdir
2019-02-25 15:39:54.330 23934-23934/com.someapp D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libyoga.so: deferring to libdir
```

However, the second time I connect I see this:

```
2019-02-25 15:47:45.626 25734-25734/com.someapp I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.someapp/lib-main
```

with all other logs being identical to that point.